# Get data from webpage that use ajax function using VBA Excel

Tags: ajax, excel, vba, extract, html

I want to extract data from http://www.fipiran.com/FundDetails?regno=11186 into excel. The problem is the webpage uses ajax function and there aren't any element per each entry. This a part of html that I mentioned:

```
<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({ // Get Faculty PartialView
            url: "/Fund/MFwithRegNo",
            headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'Index' },
            contentType: 'application/html;charset=utf-8',
            type: 'Get',
            data: { 'regno': '11186' },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#CMFAll").html(data);
                $('#imgMFAll').hide();

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

How can I extract the data in the webpage such as: `تاریخ بروز رسانی` ?

Comment: I have not used VBA to do web scraping, but I am almost certain that if a webpage is not pure html you cannot extract the java script or ajax built parts. This is already a big challenge in known and recent libraries, let alone VBA that is old

Comment: I have to use VBA  because my data is in EXCEL. I'm sure must be a way for it!

Comment: No, you don't have to. Personally, I have written a code to do scraping in python and I import and export data from Excel so you are not limited to VBA

Answer (score 0):

Use a method that can handle slowly loading pages. For example, use Internet Explorer and introduce a loop until an expected element on the page is set (with timeout to prevent infinite looping).

I am going to show using [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) as selenium is by far my preferred method for handling slowly loading pages. Script below using CSS selector combination to target the element by its parent class, and element tag (`div`), and position within returned list.

**Target:**

[image: target]

**Selector combination:**

```
.clearfix.header_company div
```

Of the `divs` within the parent with class `clearfix header_company`, the required element is at index 10.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "http://www.fipiran.com/FundDetails?regno=11186"

    With d
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url
        Debug.Print .FindElementsByCss(".clearfix.header_company div", timeout:=2000)(10).Text
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```